# Akka and simple local cache (possibly Guava)

Tags: scala, caching, akka, guava

I recently started using Akka with Scala and I have a question about caching data (result of some expensive computation). Ideally, I'd like to use something like a Guava cache to take advantage of automatic cache eviction and concurrent writes capability. However, I am not exactly sure what the best way to integrate an instance of a Guava cache with my actors is.

I have a set of actors that return the result of the computation by either returning a cached value or by computing the value, storing it in the cache and then returning it. All of these actors should share the same (JVM-local) cache. The cache can be easily populated using a cache loader.

Now my question is: what are the Akka best practices to do so? Is Guava a good idea or are there other Akka-friendly libraries? How would I inject the cache into the actors? Should I use a parent that creates it and keeps a reference around and then injects it into the children when they are created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spray Caching](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2-RC4/spray-caching/) would be a better alternative to Guava Caching because you're already using Scala and Akka. It's a simple in memory cache based on Scala Futures.

Comment: I'm still not sure about the way to integrate the cache with my actors. If I was using a traditional java concurrency model, the cache would be shared and could be concurrently accessed by multiple clients. What's the equivalent of that in Akka? Do I inject the same instance of the cache in all the actors that need it? What about concurrency? Is the cache thread-safe? Does spray-cache support concurrency levels like the Guava cache?

Comment: @vptheron's suggestion would work along with the Spray Cache and you could have one caching actor because it would be completely non-blocking and fast and then you could proxy to the actor(s) doing the computation whether that is various actors or actors behind an Akka router.

Answer (score 2):

An idea would be to use a caching actor to proxy the computing actors.

Let's say you have a client C who wants to compute cool things. C send a message to CachingActor. CachingActor has an instance of Guava cache (or something else), so it first check its cache to see if it already has the answer. If it does it returns it, otherwise it can ask the set of actors to compute it, cache the response and return it to C.

Comment: So the cache would be shared among as many actors as they need it?

Comment: One actor would handle the caching, so you would have only one instance of the cache (so I guess you could say it's shared among all actors). Your set of actors would be children of the caching actor, the caching actor would query them if its internal cache does not contain the computation for a certain client request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well it will fit your use case but I wrote a [guest post](http://letitcrash.com/post/30509298968/case-study-an-auto-updating-cache-using-actors) for Akka's [Let it Crash](http://letitcrash.com/) blog about a actor-based caching system for a slow backend.   It uses EhCache but it could be easily swapped for another cache implementation.